# Insert something .after a set of elements if the first in the set has a certain class

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a label AFTER a group of radio inputs IF the first has a certain class

```
<label>Has the strategy and all of it's relevant background documents been uploaded</label>

<label for="Radio1"><input type="radio" name="uploaded" class="required cat1" id="Radio1">Yes</label>

<label for="Radio2"><input type="radio" name="uploaded" id="Radio2">No</label>
```

Radio1 has the class, but I'd like to insert a label after the last (in this case Radio2)

I thought I could use this:

```
$('input[type="radio"].cat1').siblings('input:last').after('<label>Hi!</label>');
```

But it doesn't work. Can you pick what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong: the element matching selector `input[type="radio"].cat1` has no siblings (other than one [or more] text nodes containing the characters `Yes`, to get technical). Text nodes aside, it is the sole child of a `<label>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('input[type="radio"].cat1')
    .parent().parent()
    .find('label:last')
    .after('<label>Hi!</label>');
```

So find the radio button with required class, go to its parent (label) then the parent of that (whatever your container is) then find the last label and append a label after it.

Edit: didnt notice your inputs were nested in a label. have fixed for that. Also you may need to tweak selectors a bit depending on your requirements.

Comment: Great. I think I got that selector slightly incorrect too: input[type="radio"] should be input:radio (iirc)

Comment: both of those selectors are valid and do the same thing